# Referencing values in rows, base on column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i need a formula to reference 3 different rows, depending on which column i paste into.
What i know is 
 the width is constant, 34 columns across

i want to paste into columns A1, L1, W1
I want to retrieve the values for cells, AK1,AK2,AK3

im using this at the moment to grab parts of the text in that cell. eg

```
="<tag" &MID($AK3,FIND(" ",$AK3),FIND(" ",$AK3,FIND("1",$AK3))-FIND(" ",$AK3))&" endtext>"
```

my idea was when i paste into column 22 i need something to return the number 2, pass that to an offset formula on AK1, as this is 2 thirds the way across, then i can reference 2 rows down from AK1 and get the value.

Hope that makes sense.

Here is an example. Cells A1 C1 E1 are retrieved from  the H column

[image]

Comment: So you want to put a formula in either A1,L1 or W1 and pull from AK1:AK3 depending on the column. So when you put the formula in A2, should it pull info from AK2? Can you include some sample data with expected output. Right now I'm thinking along the lines of `=INDEX(AK1:AK3,MATCH(COLUMN(),{1,12,23},0))`

Comment: yes A1, gets me ak1, L2 gets me ak2 so as i go across, im going down the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presume you have **named** the three values sitting in Column AK as **Rng_AK**,

when you paste this formula `=INDEX(Rng_AK,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/34*ROWS(Rng_AK),0))`

- anywhere between Column **A to K**, you will get the **first** value in the given range;
- anywhere between Column **L to V**, you will get the **second** value in the given range;
- anywhere between Column **W to AH**, you will get the **third** value in the given range;

I am using your logic of locating the value in Column AK by the relative position of the column in the 34-Columns range.

See below screen-shot for more clarifications. Cheers :)

[image: Solution]

Comment: thanks Terry spot on! what if I didnt have the column range, can I set a counter so it knows how many times the formula has been pasted (wishful thinking, as limited to folmula)

Comment: @platinums if you are certain the formula will be paste within column A to AH, you can use `COLUMNS($A:$AH)` in stead of `34` in the formula which will also return 34 as the total number of columns in this range. Not sure if this is what you were asking about?